# Does Javascript have a way of doing "find_if" or "FirstOrDefault"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, design-patterns

I'm a Junior-level JavaScript developer and I find that I often have situations where I need to do the equivalent of

```
"Find the first element satisfying a condition, then do something with the element"
```

and I end up writing a `for` loop with a `break` statement. For instance, here is a piece of production code I wrote:

```
// set up event listeners for changing the snake's direction
// based on arrows keys pressed
// see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226859/how-can-i-track-arrow-keys-in-chrome-and-ie
var arrowKeyMap = { 37 : "left", 38: "down", 39: "right", 40: "up" };
$(document).keydown(function (e)
{
    // want to make this more compact ...
    for (var i in arrowKeyMap)
    {
        if (i == e.keyCode)
        {
            SG.snake.changeDirection(arrowKeyMap[i]);  
            break;
        }
    }

});
```

I want to know if there is a native JavaScript tool, or a way using JQuery, make that more compact, or if I need to hand-roll a reusable procedure for situations like this. I know that C# has a `FirstOrDefault` and C++  a `find_if` which are kinda like what I want.

Comment: Questions asking for a tool, lib etc. are considered off topic... have you looked at underscore.js?

Comment: Yes, see [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already got the mapping, javascript's `Object` allows you to directly lookup by `key`, just check if the object with the `key` is exist or not.

So you can just use the `e.keyCode` as key to find if there's a mapping to it.

```
var arrowKeyMap = { 37 : "left", 38: "down", 39: "right", 40: "up" };
$(document).keydown(function (e)
{
    var key = arrowKeyMap[e.keyCode];
    if (key) { // Do something if there's a map to the key.
       SG.snake.changeDirection(key );  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking too much in terms of algorithms. Think instead in terms of data structures:

```
if (arrowKeyMap[e.keyCode]) { // keymap exist?
    SG.snake.changeDirection(arrowKeyMap[e.keyCode]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSLinq. It provides the same linq functions for js those are available for c#.